# Excel telling me it can't access a file I don't want it to access

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a long project and there are many betas with overlapping functionality. I keep raising the number of the beta after making substantial changes.

This file imports a bunch of data from spreadsheets which are exported feeds from a SQL database. It does this with no problem and that part of it has been working for months - importing some raw data sheets and using both cell references and VB to look at it different ways, and I set up a checklist page where the end user can go through certain records one by one and classify them.

All of this works fine and I really only made a few changes today, just finishing off little bits of code that take some data from one sheet and rearrange it in another to export. It was all working with no errors and I copied the file into a new folder (which I have been doing with these templates for months), imported my data (test data in this case), and tried to run the function that copies some info from one sheet onto an another.

Then I get an error from Excel that says "we can't connect to 'https://...my.sharepoint../BETAV9_8_ItemAccountingTEMPLATEetcetc. Please make sure you're using correct web address."

After that I click OK and then I get a second message that says:

Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'same file' There are several possible reasons:
The file name or path does not exist
The file is being used by another program
The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook

This file they're telling me they can't find is like 3 betas ago and I've been using subsequent versions without getting this error. That file isn't in the current working folder, nor in the folder from which I copied it originally.

So I'm thinking I have something in my file where there's a reference to an external file, so I went through this process: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-links-external-references-in-a-workbook-fcbf4576-3aab-4029-ba25-54313a532ff1?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

I don't know where to begin. There is only one thing in the Name Manager (a table that I created on one of these pages with VBA so I can sort it a couple different ways) and the button that says "Delete" is grayed out. There are several references in cells to other files - but not the BETAv9_8 it's telling me it can't find. They are simply file paths/names of the files the user imported - not hidden somewhere in code, just listed on a sheet so the user can check what data she imported.

After going through all these recommended steps I still can't find anywhere in my program that mentions BETAv9_8. In the meantime I'm getting an error for a thing that worked just fine a couple hours ago.

Is this a bug? Is there something I can do to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you look at linked workbooks?

Comment: Hi @NickPerkins thank you for answering. Do you mean look in other workbooks besides the one that's giving me the error? I've only got the one workbook open. Are you saying the error could be coming from a completely different file? I tried as hard as I could to find links to other workbooks in the file in question, using the MS URL above. I'm not finding any links to other workbooks.